# highcharts ganttchart misaligned tooltip and bar spacing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using the gantt chart using highcharts. I found few issues from the demo one.
https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/804783-gantt-chart

Please check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv976a1r/2/)

Aligning multiple bar lines into one section, this is not working properly. Space for Project 2 is assigned in Development even if there is no data. Also the tootip is misaligned. I have spent a lot of time to figure it out, but has been unsuccessful. Can anyone help me fix this.

```
$(function () {

    /**
     * Highcharts X-range series plugin
     */
    (function (H) {
        var defaultPlotOptions = H.getOptions().plotOptions,
            columnType = H.seriesTypes.column,
            each = H.each,
            extendClass = H.extendClass,
            pick = H.pick,
            Point = H.Point;

        defaultPlotOptions.xrange = H.merge(defaultPlotOptions.column, {
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.yCategory}</b><br/>'
            }
        });
        H.seriesTypes.xrange = H.extendClass(columnType, {
            pointClass: extendClass(Point, {
                // Add x2 and yCategory to the available properties for tooltip formats
                getLabelConfig: function () {
                    var cfg = Point.prototype.getLabelConfig.call(this);

                    cfg.x2 = this.x2;
                    cfg.yCategory = this.yCategory = this.series.yAxis.categories && this.series.yAxis.categories[this.y];
                    return cfg;
                }
            }),
            type: 'xrange',
            forceDL: true,
            parallelArrays: ['x', 'x2', 'y'],
            requireSorting: false,
            animate: H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.animate,

            /**
             * Borrow the column series metrics, but with swapped axes. This gives free access
             * to features like groupPadding, grouping, pointWidth etc.
             */
            getColumnMetrics: function () {
                var metrics,
                    chart = this.chart;

                function swapAxes() {
                    each(chart.series, function (s) {
                        var xAxis = s.xAxis;
                        s.xAxis = s.yAxis;
                        s.yAxis = xAxis;
                    });
                }

                swapAxes();

                this.yAxis.closestPointRange = 1;
                metrics = columnType.prototype.getColumnMetrics.call(this);

                swapAxes();

                return metrics;
            },
            translate: function () {
                columnType.prototype.translate.apply(this, arguments);
                var series = this,
                    xAxis = series.xAxis,
                    metrics = series.columnMetrics,
                    minPointLength = series.options.minPointLength || 0;

                H.each(series.points, function (point) {
                    var barWidth = Math.min(
                            xAxis.translate(H.pick(point.x2, point.x + (point.len || 0))) - point.plotX,
                            xAxis.len
                        ),
                        barWidthDifference = barWidth < minPointLength ? minPointLength - barWidth : 0;

                    point.shapeArgs = {
                        x: Math.max(0, point.plotX) - barWidthDifference / 2,
                        y: point.plotY + metrics.offset,
                        width: barWidth + barWidthDifference,
                        height: metrics.width
                    };
                    point.tooltipPos[0] += barWidth / 2;
                    point.tooltipPos[1] -= metrics.width / 2;
                });
            }
        });

        /**
         * Max x2 should be considered in xAxis extremes
         */
        H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'getSeriesExtremes', function (proceed) {
            var axis = this,
                dataMax,
                modMax;

            proceed.call(this);
            if (this.isXAxis) {
                dataMax = pick(axis.dataMax, Number.MIN_VALUE);
                each(this.series, function (series) {
                    each(series.x2Data || [], function (val) {
                        if (val > dataMax) {
                            dataMax = val;
                            modMax = true;
                        }
                    });
                });
                if (modMax) {
                    axis.dataMax = dataMax;
                }
            }
        });
    }(Highcharts));


    // THE CHART
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'xrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts X-range study'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: '',
            categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
            min: 0,
            max: 2
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
            var seriesName = this.series.name;
            return seriesName;
          },positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {         
                             var tooltipX, tooltipY;
                                if (point.plotX + labelWidth > this.chart.plotWidth) {
                                    tooltipX = point.plotX ;
                                } else {
                                    tooltipX = point.plotX + this.chart.plotLeft + 5;
                                }
                                tooltipY = point.plotY + this.chart.plotTop - 10;
                                return {
                                    x: tooltipX,
                                    y: tooltipY
                                };       
                        }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Project 1',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },
        {
            name: 'Project 2',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, /*{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            },*/ {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },
        {
            name: 'Project 3',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Project 4',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Project 5',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Project 6',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        },{
            name: 'Project 7',
            // pointPadding: 0,
            // groupPadding: 0,
            borderRadius: 5,
            pointWidth: 10,
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                y: 2
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
                y: 1
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
                x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
                y: 2
            }]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: This is default behaviour also in the column chart: http://jsfiddle.net/4prha1ky/. The workaround for bars is: http://jsfiddle.net/zmktekak/14/

Comment: @SebastianBochan I added justify Columns like you have given in your example, it doesn't work. Can you suggest me changes. here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kv976a1r/4/